# What is array subscript operator in typedef in C

Tags: c, typedef

In `libgmp` I see `typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1]`; what does `[1]` mean here?

Does it mean `typedef _mpz_struct* mpz_t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is not the same as a pointer...

It is defining a type named “`mpz_t`” which is itself an *array* of `__mpz_struct`s, where *the array is exactly one element long*.

---

A lot of times, you can figure this kind of stuff out by simply removing the `typedef` and see what kind of variable you would be creating. In this case:

```
__mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

That there is an array of `__mpz_struct`s exactly one element long, named “`mpz_t`”.

Prefix that `typedef` and now instead of declaring a variable name you are declaring a *type name*.

---

---

### ...but it effectively *is* a pass-by-reference trick

The object of our interest is part of [The GNU MP Bignum Library](https://gmplib.org), which defines it as such for a very specific purpose ...but first we need to cover some vocabulary, alas.

By default in C (and C++), function arguments ***pass by value***. In C++, you can also ***pass by reference***, meaning that the formal argument name is treated as an alias for the actual argument value.

- A **direct reference** is an alias for some value. (Not necessarily a *name*, just some kind of direct, bird-in-the-hand access to that value.)
- An **indirect reference** is an object that can be used to obtain a direct reference — in other words, a *pointer*. We *dereference* a pointer (remove its indirection) to obtain a direct reference.

```c
int   x = 12;  // `x` is a direct reference to an integer object with value 12
int & y = x;   // `y` is a direct reference to that same integer object
int * z = &x;  // `z` is an INdirect reference (pointer) to that same integer object
               // `*z` is a direct reference to that same integer object
```

But C doesn’t have a direct reference type.
So, obviously, that `y` thing doesn’t work in C.
But `*z` does.

The GNU MP library uses a sneaky trick to automagically get pass-by-reference behavior in C.

In C (and in C++) the outermost (or first) dimension of any array [automatically decays to a pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Array_to_pointer_conversion) in most contexts, including passing as argument to a function.

What that means is that passing an `mpz_t` to a function is the same as passing an (indirect) reference to it, an `__mpz_struct *`.

For example:

```
mpz_t x;       // HERE is my bignum integer. NOT A POINTER TO ONE.
some_fn( x );  // Pass an (indirect) reference to `x` as argument.
```

If `mpz_t` weren’t defined as it is, we would have to explicitly annotate that we want to pass a reference every time we called a function:

```
struct my_struct_type x;
some_fn( &x );
```

---

#### Wut? *Why!??*

GNU MP needs you to pass your bignums by reference in order to avoid **splicing**. See if you can identify the problem with the following code snippet:

```
typedef struct String { char * s; } String;

void set_string_value( String string, const char * s )  // A
{
  string.s = strdup( s );                               // B
}

char * get_string_value( String string )                // C
{
  return string.s;                                      // D
}

String greeting;
set_string_value( greeting, "Hello world!" );           // E
printf( "%s\n", get_string_value( greeting ) );         // F
```

If you observe that line `B` has got a memory leak then you got it! The argument `string` is a local *copy* of the caller’s `greeting`. Modifying it has absolutely no effect on the caller, and when the function terminates its `string` goes out of scope and is destroyed.

By the time we finish with line `E` the `greeting` object has never been modified, and attempting to print something will likely cause an access violation/segmentation fault/whatever Undefined Behavior occurs when `printf()` tries to follow that uninitialized character pointer in `greeting`.

The important point is that `set_string_value()` never modified `greeting`.

So, how do we fix it? That’s right, require line `A` to take an (indirect) *reference:*

```
void set_string_value( String * string, const char * s )  // A
{
  string->s = strdup( s );                                // B
}
    
String greeting;
set_string_value( &greeting, "Hello world!" );            // E
printf( "%s\n", get_string_value( greeting ) );
```

Now we can see how GNU MP is sneaky. Let’s rewrite that String thing again:

```
struct StringStruct { char * s; };
typedef struct StringStruct String[1];

void set_string_value( String string, const char * s )  // A
{
  string->s = strdup( s );                              // B
}

char * get_string_value( String string )                // C
{
  return string->s;                                     // D
}

String greeting;
set_string_value( greeting, "Hello world!" );           // E
printf( "%s\n", get_string_value( greeting ) );         // F
```

Substituting the type name on line `A` we see that:

```
void set_string_value( String string, const char * s )
void set_string_value( StringStruct[1] string, cosst char * s )
void set_string_value( StringStruct string[1], const char * s )
void set_string_value( StringStruct string[], const char * s )
void set_string_value( StringStruct * string, const char * s )
```

Substituting type for the `greeting` variable:

```
String greeting;
StringStruct[1] greeting;
StringStruct greeting[1];
// `greeting` is an array with one element of type StringStruct
```

And, with array-to-pointer decay, *calling* the function causes it to get a pointer to `greeting`, AKA an indirect reference.

---

#### dumb tricks...

A lot of older libraries use tricks like this. When dealing with structured types, you will often see things like:

```
Quux * x = CreateQuux(...);
DoSomeQuuxing( x );
FreeQuux( x );
```

It has been a while since I touched GNU MP directly (I tend to use [Boost.Multiprecision](https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision), which handles all the back-end details for me) so I missed the purpose discussed here.

Before [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) existed in C (literally ages ago — they were introduced in C99) people would use the hack by declaring a single-element array and simply `malloc()` more elements as needed. That was, alas, my first (and incorrect) knee-jerk reaction to it.

In today’s modern world you might say that doing stuff like this is dumb. But it is what it is, it is how C works, and a lot of legacy stuff exists that use things like this.

Who knows what GNU MP would look like if it were designed today? Maybe the same.

Comment: why would someone define a type of 1 element array?

Comment: One possible reason is to prevent silent accidental copies in function calls. With `void my_func(mpz_t a);` and `mpz_t b; my_func(b);`, `b` is passed by reference (pointer), rather than copied.

Comment: Re “Because when the object is allocated, *more than* one `__mpz_struct` is allocated in a dynamic array”: No, [GMP types are implemented as one-element arrays so that using them as parameters is effectively pass-by-reference](https://gmplib.org/manual/Variable-Conventions).